# Windows 10 - Remapping windows keys?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I'd like to map `Win+W` to behave like `Win+Tab` and `Win+Q` and `Win+E` to switch to previous and next virtual desktops respectively (What `CTRL+Win+Arrow Keys` do by default).

How can this be done? (I have AutoHotKey installed but if that's your solution please provide the script as I don't know how to script it.).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this with AutoHotKey. Quite simple.

Create a file `windows_hotkeys.ahk` somewhere, with this code:

```
;map win+q and win+e to switch between virtual desktops.
#q::#^Left
#e::#^Right

;also, map win+w to open the "window overview" thingy (what win+tab does by default)
#w::#Tab
```

Save it and right-click and "run script".

#### About the script:

`::` is used to map one hotkey to simply trigger another hotkey.

`;` is a comment.

`#` is the windows key.

`Tab` is the tab key.

`Left` and `Right` are the left and right arrow keys.

Comment: Did not work for me in Win 10. Script does not change anything.